# Redirecinamento 301 htaccess com e sem www para HTTPS

Tags: php, htaccess

Bom dia.
Gostaria de sua ajuda.

Preciso fazer um htaccess, que funcione assim:

- Redirecionar 301:  "site.com" ou "www.site.com" **para** https://www.site.com
- Se a pessoa vier de alguma url do google, e não tiver o https, forçar a entrada no https.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Para redirecionar todo trafego par HTTPs basta adicionar essa linha no seu `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Aonde o dominio.com.br é a URL do seu site, essa é a forma mais rápida que conheço.

Para fazer apenas o redirecionamento de **com www** para **sem www** adicione essas linhas no seu `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.google.com$
   RewriteRule (.*) http://google.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Para redirecionar de sem **www** para com **www** adicione essas linhas no seu `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dominio.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.dominio.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

> Troque o o dominio.com para o seu dominio,
>
> **OBS:** lembre que de trocar o **https** para **http** caso o site não tenha ssl

No sei caso por exemplo, caso queria redirecionar todo o site para https e sem o www seria:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$    
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.dominio.com.br$
    RewriteRule (.*) https://dominio.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Redireciono para o https, e após isso removo o www. do seu `dominio.com.br`, lembrando que troque para o seu dominio em questão.

Acabei achando um site bem pratico: https://www.aleydasolis.com/htaccess-redirects-generator/https-vs-http/ basta selecionar o que que e gerar.

Comment: Mas isso não verifica se esta com ou sem www

Comment: Para redirecionamento par com www e uma forma e para sem www e outra vou atualizar com as duas opções;